# Function button for WIFI ignition does not work with UBUNTU 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: wireless, 18.04, ralink, button

On my HP Pavilion g6-2306el I have an <kbd>F12</kbd> button for WiFi ignition  that works perfectly with previous Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and other OS , but unfortunately not with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. This Pavillion's  WiFi adapter is the Ralink RT5390R 802.11bgn.

**Only with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS I have this problem and I have to turn on the WI-FI via graphic interface  while the ON / OFF WIFI button does not work !!**

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?
Thanks, greetings to all

Answer (score 1):

I notice the same problem was present also on another Gnome based distro (Manjaro gnome ) and now I personally verified on my HP Pavilion g6-2306el  that with last gnome updates,  WI-FI ignition works well on that distro. So I'm very confident that in a very short time the same problem will be solved also in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS gnome based.